# How come Logcat only prints TrafficStats?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple application that connects to an FTP server using Apache Commons. I'm able to connect to the FTP server but Logcat won't print the directory.

What am I doing wrong here? Rather than printing the directory, it just prints the traffic stats.

output

```
2023-06-04 08:55:26.356 25469-25496 System.out              com.example.ftpbuddy                 I  Client logged in!
2023-06-04 08:55:26.366 25469-25496 TrafficStats            com.example.ftpbuddy                 D  tagSocket(114) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2023-06-04 08:55:26.372 25469-25469 System.out              com.example.ftpbuddy                 I  Done...
```

**FTPServices.java**

```
package com.example.ftpbuddy;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Debug;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FTPServices  {

    public void loginFtp(String host, int port, String username, String password) {
        try {
            FTPClient client = new login(host, port, username, password).execute().get();
            FTPFile[] files = new printDirectory(client, "/home/gabriel").execute().get();

            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("> " + files[i].getName());
            }

            System.out.println("Done...");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, FTPClient> {

        private String host;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private int port;

        login(String host, int port, String username, String password)
        {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.password = password;
            this.username = username;
        }
        @Override
        protected FTPClient doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
                client.connect(host, port);
                client.login(username, password);
                System.out.println("Client logged in!");

                return client;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class printDirectory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, FTPFile[]> {

        private FTPClient client;
        private String directory;

        printDirectory(FTPClient client, String directory) {
            this.client = client;
            this.directory = directory;
        }

        @Override
        protected FTPFile[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                FTPFile[] files = this.client.listFiles(this.directory);
                return files;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**ConnectActivity.java**

```
package com.example.ftpbuddy;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class ConnectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etHost;
    EditText etPort;
    EditText etUsername;
    EditText etPassword;
    Button btnConnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        etHost = findViewById(R.id.etHost);
        etPort = findViewById(R.id.etPort);
        etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);

        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new ConnectButtonHandler());
    }

    public class ConnectButtonHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FTPServices services = new FTPServices();
            services.loginFtp(
                    etHost.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString()),
                    etUsername.getText().toString(),
                    etPassword.getText().toString()
            );


        }
    }

}
```

I understand that AsyncTask is deprecated, and I'm still very new to Android Development. I just don't understand why it doesn't print the file names in the given directory.

If someone could help guide me to the right direction, that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Most likely the error is in the class `printDirectory`.